# Must models of the following theory satisfying opposing infinitary sentences, satisfy opposing finitary sentences?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, constructibility, infinitary-logic

This is a follow-up to posting titled ["Is this theory finitary first order complete?"](https://mathoverflow.net/q/449922/95347)

Recall the theory presented at that posting. Replace the size axiom by the following:

$\textbf{Minimality: } \not \exists \alpha: L_\alpha \models \sf ZFC$

Where $L_\alpha \models \sf ZFC$, is defined as $\bigwedge {\sf A^{L_\alpha}}$

Where $\sf A^{L_\alpha}$ is all $\mathcal A^{L_\alpha}_{i \in \omega}$ formulas where $\mathcal A_i$ is an axiom of $\sf ZFC$ and $\mathcal A^{L_\alpha}_i $ is the formula obtained by merely bounding all quantifiers occurring in $\mathcal A_i$ by $``\in L_\alpha"$.

Now the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/449963/95347) to the prior posting, shows that the existence of $L_\alpha$ stages satisfying $\sf ZFC$ is not determined. But, here this will be determined to the negative, and seemingly we are speaking about the Shepherdson-Cohen model (i.e.; the minimal transitive model of $\sf ZFC$). But, since Foundation is not captured in $\mathcal L_{\lambda, \omega}$ languages, then there will be models satisfying different infinitary foundation statements.

> Now, my question is that those models are differing on infinitary statements. So, is there a proof that such differences must lead to models satisfying different finitary statements?

> If not, then can this strengthening of the referred theory be, as intended, finitary complete?

Comment: Any two countable models which are not isomorphic disagree about a sentence of $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$ (by Scott's theorem). But of course we can have two non-isomorphic countable models which are elementarily equivalent. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @AlexKruckman you mean ...elementarily equivalent on finitary formulas. So, it partially answers the question. What remains is the answer to the specific issue of finitary completeness of the strengthened theory, which is the main question.

Comment: Yes, the term "elementarily equivalent refers to the *elementary* sentences: those of finitary first-order logic. If the second question is the main one, I recommend editing the title to reflect that.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, yes of course, the question is about this theory and models are about this particular theory and not a very general question. I've edited. Thanks!